# Compile-time validation of the caller, or is it possible to extend C# compiler?

Tags: c#, validation, compiler-construction, attributes, compile-time

Consider this method and the description:

```
[Description("It must be called from a property, else it is a runtime error.")]
protected T Load<T>()
{
   return InternalLoad<T>();
}
```

The design of this method *requires* that the caller *must* be a property, othewise `InternalLoad` throws an exception. It uses [StackFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx) to get the caller name, and if it is not of the form of `get_<PropertyName>` or `set_<PropertyName>`, it throws an exception. It all happens at runtime which I don't like.

I want to know if there is any way to make sure **at compile-time** that the caller is always a property. In other words, only properties should be  allowed to call this method. Is there any way to check that at **compile-time**?

As a last resort, is it possible to extend the C# compiler which would use a custom attribute (such as `CallableFromAttribute`) to make sure that?

I want to make it as much flexible as possible:

```
[CallableFrom(Caller.Property)] //Caller is an enum
protected T Load<T>()
{
   return InternalLoad<T>();
}

[CallableFrom(Caller.Property | Caller.Method)]
protected T SomeOtherLoad<T>()
{
  //code
}
```

and then

```
public string Method()
{
    var x = this.SomeOtherLoad<string>(); //okay
    var y = this.Load<string>();          //compilation error !!
}
```

Let me know if there is any confusion. I will clarify it. :-)

---

I need this feature because I'm trying to implement a class called `PropertyManager` which  serves as *base* class for other classes which need to define properties. The typical use of this class would be this:

```
public sealed Vendor : PropertyManager
{
    public string VendorName
    {
       get { return this.Load<string>(); }
       set { this.Store(value); }
    }
    public DateTime Created
    {
       get { return this.Load<DateTime>(); }
       set { this.Store(value); }
    }
}
```

Here `Load` and `Store` methods, defined in the base class, discover the *name* of property from which they're invoked; treating that name as *key*, it reads the associated value from a dictionary (in case of `Load`), or writes to it (in case of `Store`).  It raises property changing and changed events. It also supports undo, as `ProperyMananger` can easily keep track of all changes made to a property.

Comment: Seems to me, you should create postbuild task that will inspect your assembly and inject caller checking. May be [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) will help you.

Comment: I think it maybe could be done when using the new roslyn compiler services but i think the afford to do this will never get paid back.

Comment: Creating a custom FxCop rule seems the way to go.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I've heard of it. Can you elaborate on it *if* you think it could help in some way?

Comment: ....Or maybe, **StyleCop** could help (since it analyzes the source code instead of compiled-code)? Anybody has any idea?

Comment: This is remarkably bad idea.  Not sharing why you need to do this so we can offer better suggestions makes this the epitome of a too localized question.

Comment: @HansPassant: Added why I need this. See the edit.

Comment: This little conundrum is probably also the reason why NHibernate generates proxy classes that inherit YOUR object at runtime to handle propertychange events -- rather than the other way around (this way).  You're forcing all consumers of your baseclass to add this boilerplate code.

Comment: @hometoast: I'm **not** "forcing" others. It is for OUR use. Also, not every class is going to derive from this class. That simply does not make sense. Derive from it when it makes sense. Where do you see "forcing"?

Comment: What's wrong with a runtime check? I don't see any gain from doing it at compile time. But its obviously weak security wise to do it at compile time.

Comment: @Adrian: Why do you need statically-typed languages? Sooner you find the bug, better is the situation. Compilers help find the bugs sooner. Plus, it also produces faster code, as the checks has been done at compile-time, no runtime checks needed.

Comment: @Nawaz, no intention of attacking you. I meant if your users (internal or whatever) are going to use it, then there's this boiler plate to be needed. I just wanted to show a large and widely used project tracks property changes and how it's remarkably the upside-down version of what you're attempting to do. So relax, it's just a comment.

Comment: @hometoast: I don't understand that. If the decision whether to derive or not derive from it, is with you all the time, then I don't understand how it produces boiler-plate code. It in fact reduces it, as you can see there are no backup fields for the properties.

Comment: "It uses StackFrame to get the caller name" Doesn't that cause bugs due to inlining? Consider using `CallerMemberNameAttribute` or lambdas.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: `CallerMemberNameAttribute` is available from C# 4.5. I'm using C# 4.0. How would lambdas help here? You mean lambda *expression*?

Comment: In C# 4.0 you'll need to use lambda expressions or strings to identify the property. Your current code is simply broken. (At least if you don't add `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` to *every property* that calls `Load` and to `Load` itself. And even then it's bad design.)

Comment: @Nawaz There is no C# 4.5. `CallerMemberNameAttribute` is available from C# 5, regardless of which version of .NET Framework you're targeting. (You may need to create the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` class manually, but as long as it's in the right namespace, it should be getting the right compiler magic.)

Comment: @hvd: Ohh.. I meant .NET 4.5

Comment: @Nawaz Hence my comment :) As long as you use the C# 5 compiler, you should be able to use `CallerMemberNameAttribute` even in .NET 4.0 or earlier.

Comment: @hvd: How can I have C# 5 compiler, without installing VS2012?

Comment: @Nawaz If you can install .NET Framework 4.5 on your development system, you can get VS 2010 to use that compiler by adding `<UseHostCompilerIfAvailable>false</UseHostCompilerIfAvailable>` to your project file. It has some potential performance drawbacks, but nothing that I noticed when I used it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such possibility at compile time. There cannot be: all such compile-time checks are based on whether a method is accessible from the method that accesses it, *not* the method that calls it. If a property setter exposes `Load` via a delegate, there is no possible way even in a theoretical modified compiler to check at compile time that nobody uses that delegate other than another property setter.

I'm not sure why you want this, so I'm assuming that your check is necessary and your runtime check verifies exactly what you need it to. If that assumption is wrong, there may be some options, but your question as asked is simply impossible.